# Deriving the sampling probability of a unit for any sampling method

Tags: probability, sampling

in my lecture our professor said the following:
Given a population of `N`, where each unit has the same probability to get chosen, and a sampling method where the population is divided to samples of size `n` for all possible samples, the sampling probability for each unit in the population will be `n/N`.

It sounds rather counter intuitive - I know it's true for a simple random sample, but how can I derive the general case?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of a unit being selected in sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487874/probability-of-a-unit-being-selected-in-sample)

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen not quite, this talks about specific sampling methods - not the general case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to prove this, but I think it does the job.

Suppose $\{M\}_i \subset \{1,\ldots, N\}, i \in 1,\ldots,K, |\{M\}| = n$ is a collection of $K$ possible samples of size $n$ from the population, not necessarily containing all possible subsets of size $n$. Let $\{m\}$ be sampled from $\{M\}_i$ with probabilities $p_1, \ldots, p_K$, not necessarily equal. But assume that this entire construction is such that the probability that individual $j$ is in $\{m\}$, say $q_j$, is equal for all $j$, $q_j = q, j \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$

Define $I_j, j \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$ to be an indicator function, taking value 1 if $j$ is in $\{m\}$ and 0 otherwise. Then the expected value of $I_j$ is equal to $q_j = q$.

Sum the $N$ indicator functions, $\sum_{j=1}^{N} I_j$. The sum now counts how many individuals were in $\{m\}$. But $|\{m\}| = n$ for all possible samples. Therefore $\sum_{j=1}^{N} I_j = n$. Take expectations of both sides. As $n$ is constant, $E[n] = n$.

$E[\sum_{j=1}^{N} I_j] = n$

By linearity of expectation,

$\sum_{j=1}^{N} E[I_j] = n$

Since $E[I_j] = q$,

$\sum_{j=1}^{N} q = n$

$ q = n/N$

Comment: Great proof. super clear and understandable. thanks!